# How to create and push dynamic elements in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

```
static Map<Integer,HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>> maps = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>>();
```

I want to insert the elements inside the HashMap I declared above , the inner most hashmap has values ready which I can use , now I am using it like ,

```
static Map<String,String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();

maps.put(1, new HashMap<<new String("")>, values>());
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I dont quite understand question. What exactly do you need ?

Comment: I want to insert the values in my maps (hashmap) , how will I be able to ?

Comment: Do you mean `maps.get(1).put("", values);`? / Mutable statics are evil. You may be better off with a key object instead of nested maps. It's convention to use `Map` as an interface type, so `Map<Integer<Map<String,Map<String,String>>> maps = new HashMap<>();`.

Comment: and how to iterate over such nested hashmaps ?

Comment: you can iterrate only with 3 foreach cycles

Answer (score 3):

```
static Map<String,String> values1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
static Map<String,Map<String,String>> values2 = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();

values2.put("", values1);
maps.put(1,values2);
```

btw, if you have java 7, you can use:

```
Map<String,String> values1 = new HashMap<>();
```

and so on for others

Comment: My Question is quiet different

Comment: ye missclicked... so what's your question?

Comment: Thanks though it helped me to nail down while defining the Map types

Answer (score 1):

In cases you have map inside a map (inside a map), consider using Apache [MultiKeyMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiKeyMap.html#mapIterator%28%29).

- Coding will be more intuitive
- It will improve the readability of your code
- It will prevent many `if(map.get(key) != null)` blocks you will probably have in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to have instance of HashMap. When you wan to insert new value, you need to have Integer, String, String key and String value.
You continuously select nested HashMaps according to keys and then insert value to the most inner HashMap.

`map.get(key1).get(key2).insert(key3, value)`